# inserting data in database using oop php in MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

on insert/index.php
    form on page

```
<form action="insert/run" method="post">
<input type="text" name="data"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

on controller/insert.php
form rendering from this page

```
<?php
class Insert extends Controller 
{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
function index() {
    $this->view->render('insert/index');
}
    function run()
    {
            $this->model->run();
    }
}
```

on model/insert_model.php
the model how it will insert data into data base

```
<?php

class Insert_Model extends Model

{

public function __construct()

{

        parent::__construct();

}
    public function run()
    {

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (data) value ");
    }
}
```

how inserting query works

Comment: What does not work? Is it not getting uplodaed into your database? Are you sure you have the table names / column names right?

Comment: where are you getting the post data ?

Comment: what are you trying to ask ??

Comment: Are you want an explanation how it's happening.

Comment: i solve it we getting data in array thats why we have to use array to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// on  model

```
    part of code in model

    function run() {
    $data  = array();

    $data['data'] = $_POST['data'];

    $this->model->run($data);
}
```

// on controller

```
      part of code in controller

      public function run($data)
       {
          $stam =  $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (`data`) VALUES (:data)');

          $stam->execute(array(
           ':data' => $data['data']
                ));
    }
```

that will be perfact

Answer (score 0):

On your controller

```
 function run() {
        $data  = array();

        $data['data'] = $_POST['data'];

        $this->model->run($data);
    }
```

On your model

```
public function run($data) {

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (data) values :data");

    $sth->bindValue(":data", $data['data']);

    $sth->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="insert/run" method="post">
```

change to

```
<form action="<?=site_url('insert/run');?>" method="post">
```

Model:

```
//change this
 public function run()
    {

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO data (data) value ");
    }

//to this

public function run($data)
    {

       $this->db->insert("tablename",$data);
    }
```

Controller:

```
//add this to your controller
function run()
    {
            $data = array('column1' => $this->input->post('data')
                          );
            $this->model->run($data);
    }
```